Simple applescript to copy files from SD Card?
I'm sure this is simple enough to most, but I am just starting to play around with Apple script.
I simply want to have a destination folder highlighted in finder and run a script that will copy all my photo and video files from an inserted SD card to that highlighted folder.
Basically just a quick way to offload files since I do this frequently.
Could anybody help get me started? Any info would be appreciated.
Thanks!

If you must use Apple's tools, I'd recommend starting with Automator instead of AppleScript. I have almost no experience with Automator, but with some help I got from @Mockman in this Q&A I was able to build a couple of working apps.  One of the keys for me was using Automator to handle the GUI stuff, and connecting that to shell scripts I wrote. Maybe this would work for you as well?

IOW - maybe if you can get Automator to control the Photo Importer described in the answer below?

Prebuilt Shortcut
Apple's Shortcuts application includes a prebuilt Photo Importer with Redundant Copy shortcut. The shortcut's description reads:

Copy a folder of content (like photos from an SD card) to your device, rename the folder using a custom prefix you choose, make a backup copy, and notify you when it’s done


This might be an easier starting point for automating the task.
Scripted Triggering
Assuming a shortcut is called say-hello…
The macOS command line tool /usr/bin/shortcuts can run the shortcut with:
shortcuts say-hello

Alternatively, an AppleScript can use the invisible Shortcut Events application with:
tell application "Shortcuts Events"
    run shortcut "say-hello"
end tell


That does sound like a good option. The reason I'm trying to do it with a script is so I can assign it to one of my touch-screen buttons on a Loupedeck.  The backup also isn't needed.

The answer has been updated to show how a Shortcut can be integrated with a shell script or AppleScript. Hope this helps.
